# How to resolve the SMTP not connect to server drupal?

Tags: 7

I have used the SMTP Module for sending mails and done all the configuration according to this link(URL: http://www.symphonythemes.com/drupal-blog/configure-drupal-smtp-gmail).

But I could not send a mail. The error is like phpmailerException: SMTP Error: Could not authenticate. in PHPMailer->SmtpConnect().

Please help me, How to sort out this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using gmail account for SMTP then you need to enable "Allow less secure apps: ON" under "sign-in & security" of you google account settings.